# Anaconda installed PyTorch is throwing runtime error while trying to access GPU

Tags: anaconda, pytorch

```
  **~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py in _lazy_init()

168         # This function throws if there's a driver initialization error, no GPUs

169         # are found or any other error occurs

170         torch._C._cuda_init()

171         # Some of the queued calls may reentrantly call _lazy_init();

172         # we need to just return without initializing in that c**ase.

      RuntimeError: CUDA driver initialization failed, you might not have a CUDA gpu.
```

[image: nvidia SMI]

As seen above, I have already cheacked my gpu drivers.

My cuda version and gpu drivers:

- PyTorch 1.8.1
- CUDA 11.1.1
- cudnn 8.0

Comment: A couple of comments - (a) it is unnecessary and discouraged to add things like "please help" to a question. This is a question & answer site, the whole reason anyone is here is help. (b) Your question is not a CUDA programming question. You have shown you have a functioning driver and it is pretty obvious that your issue is related to either PyTorch or the environment in which it is running. That is why I edited your question the way I have and why it should stay that way.

Comment: thank you i am new i didn't know the standards sorry